# Changing text color of datepicker

Tags: swift, ios8, datepicker

Is it any way to change text color of datepicker in iOS8? I've that it isn't possible in iOS7 and prior, something changed in 8th version?

For example I've found modified picker in Yahoo Weather!

[image]

Comment: Well you're not supposed to customize it.  :-) Bet you could if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found solution at [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28420738/4532985) of stackoverflow. If you need just to 
change text color to yours and assign this subclass you your picker. For whiteColor works as magic.

Only minus i've found that color two lines of selected number is still gray.

```
class ColoredDatePicker: UIDatePicker {
    var changed = false
    override func addSubview(view: UIView) {
        if !changed {
            changed = true
            self.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
        }
        super.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Comment: The "only minus"? Anything that doesn't look perfect is a *huge* minus for discerning apps and customers. It isn't adequately supported by Apple *yet*.

Answer (score 78):

**Still Works, Swift 4 Update**

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

This works for me.

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

Comment: [datePicker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"textColor"];
- in Objective-C

Comment: I did this but the current date is still Black color. Any idea what can I do instead?

Comment: I had the same issue... it changes all the other dates except the current one.

Comment: Anybody find a fix for current date being black?

Comment: Working fine for me with. No problems with the current date being black.

Comment: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_UIAppearance 0x280a0b0f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key textColor.'

Comment: Not working with .inline date picker style

Comment: @PavanKotesh May be is the appDelegate.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark only in dark mode, the current date will change to white.

Answer (score 33):

It's working on iOS 10 only if you set both properties.

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
datePicker.setValue(false, forKeyPath: "highlightsToday")
```

Comment: The second line gives me an error:
Thread 1: "-[_UIDatePickerCalendarView setHighlightsToday:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b50000c3800"

Answer (score 24):

I've changed text color through inspector (see below)

[image]

Comment: Some dates are blacked

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want the selected text to be black at start you need to set both textColor and highlightsToday :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

setting text color for all date picker subviews

```
for view in datePicker.subviews {
    view.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
}
```

Possible duplicate: [Set text color and font for UIDatePicker in iOS8/Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417217/set-text-color-and-font-for-uidatepicker-in-ios8-swift/60341443#60341443)

Answer (score 1):

Resolving the issue with black "Today" via highlightsToday set to "false" has a side-effect - it's no longer has "Today" label in the list.

I've found a different solution here which works perfect without any side-effects:
[Set text color and font for UIDatePicker in iOS8/Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417217/set-text-color-and-font-for-uidatepicker-in-ios8-swift/33459744)

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
datePicker.datePickerMode = .CountDownTimer
datePicker.datePickerMode = .DateAndTime //or whatever your original mode was
```

Looks like a dirty hack but that's we have at the moment: changing datePickerMode re-draws it correctly. So just set it to something different from your desired mode and change it back to original.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that wasnt listed here or in the other thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59838215/4266735

I ran into a similar issue with the latest SwiftUI / Swift 5 on XCode 11. All of the options above did not work and the DatePicker either stayed black text or crashed.

In your SwiftUI file set init() before var body

```
init() {
    UIDatePicker.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Then in your var body view do this

```
DatePicker(selection: $dob, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
   Text("Select Date")
}.colorInvert()
```

That inverted the black text to be white using the iOS Dark Theme. Looks/works great. Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe using .colorScheme(.light)  will be better then inverting colours