# How to Change UIDatePicker Selected Color and Font Without Being Hacky in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

A lot of the answers I've seen to this question are either in Objective-C, hacky solutions, or solutions that don't answer the entire question.

I've been able to change the non-selected values colors using:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

Is there a way to change the selected date's color and font from a UIDatePicker without being hacky?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The only known [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220535/changing-text-color-of-datepicker) to change the color of the selected date in Swift (along with the rest of the text) is, indeed, hacky because making font/text color alterations to UIDatePicker [isn't supported](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker) by the Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

`birthdayPicker.performSelector("setHighlightsToday:", withObject:UIColor.whiteColor())`

Answer (score -2):

Swift 4

datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")