# changed UIDatePick textColor but AM PM color not change

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

When I changed `UIDatePicker` `textColor`, but the "AM PM" color not change, how to fix it 
I use this code:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XL0J.png)

Comment: datePicker.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

Comment: I try this already, but not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by applying `tintColor` to datePicker?

You should try it like,

```
datePicker.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

This will change your datePicker colour. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220535/changing-text-color-of-datepicker