# How to change DatePicker's texts color in SwiftUI?

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

I saw this question but it doesn't work in SwiftUI.

> [Changing text color of datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220535/changing-text-color-of-datepicker)

I tried `.forgroundColor` and `.accentColor` but they don't change the texts' color.

Answer (score 17):

Using `.colorInvert()` and `.colorMultiply(.white)` will change the text color to white but won't work when the device is in Dark Mode. Instead, try this:

```
DatePicker("Date", selection: $selection)
    .colorScheme(.dark) // or .light to get black text
```

Comment: This is the best answer currently, but hope that Apple will give us the way to change text color in the future

Answer (score 13):

try this:

```
var body: some View {
    Group {
        
        DatePicker(selection: $selected) {
            Text("Date")
        }
    
    .colorInvert()
        .colorMultiply(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, be worry that it could change the functionality of some controls. try to apply the same technic on Toggle and it stops working ...

Comment: @UserWithWeiredNumber. nobody said it will work on all controls. nobody said - and each developer knows - Apple can change things and then we have to change some things too. But some people only see "worries". He asked for changing the color of the datepicker - he searches for a solution NOW - not in 100 years. that is what my solution provides. nothing more nothing less.

Comment: I already choose your answer as valuable :-), it is still a good idea to inform the people. Especially because the Toggle could be deeper in your UI. You can try it yourself ... To be warned is better

Comment: i cannot see who flagged my answers... ;)

Answer (score 13):

I just simple set the accentColor and it works.

```
@State private var date = Date()
DatePicker("Select a date",
           selection: $date, in: ...Date(), 
           displayedComponents: .date)
        .labelsHidden()
        .accentColor(.orange)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - duplicate post with accepted answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/64823381/5632572

Comment: For the `.compact` date picker style this accent color is shown when active, but the text is black before the control is tapped.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. This ONLY colors the accented buttons, like the <> arrows and the selected date, everything else is unaffected.

Comment: .accentColor() will be deprecated in the near future.
For the @pkamb comment use tint also.

Answer (score 5):

you can do this to make the text appear white in light or dark mode if you use a background color

```
struct PickerDate: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var date: Date
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Record Date", selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
                .labelsHidden()
                .colorMultiply(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                .colorInvert()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use extension for customized text color for both of light mode and dark mode.

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func changeTextColor(_ color: Color) -> some View {
        if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
            self.colorInvert().colorMultiply(color)
        } else {
            self.colorMultiply(color)
        }
    }
}
```

and sample is as below.

```
DatePicker("Date", selection: $selection)
    .labelsHidden()
    .changeTextColor(.green)
```

Comment: bear in mind that `userInterfaceStyle` doesn't change if the view is modified with `preferredColorScheme`, so using the value from the environment may be required

Comment: This same logic is what I used along with the `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme` variable that I believe @CMash is referring to. Thanks for providing the solution to only apply `.colorInvert()` if the user's device is in light mode.

Answer (score 2):

I found applying this modifier to the `DatePicker` to be cleaner:

**Forces the color to white**

```
 .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
```

**Forces the color to dark**

```
 .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
```

Answer (score 1):

.accentColor() will be deprecated in the near future.

.colorInvert() will stop working as soon as tapped.

For now im using:

```
.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
.tint(baby.color.bgColor)
.colorMultiply(baby.color.bgColor)
```

But using .preferredColorScheme(.dark) in some cases affects all the view tones depending on the colors you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePicker("DatePicker", selection: self.$date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
              .labelsHidden()
              .colorMultiply(Color.white)
              .colorInvert()
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks