# Change font color in new DatePicker (iOS14)

Tags: colors, datepicker, swiftui, ios14

How can i change foreground color in new DatePicker for iOS 14?

```
VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0)
{
    DatePicker(selection: self.$enddate, in: self.endMinDate()...self.endMaxDate()) {
        Text("Start")
    }.labelsHidden().colorMultiply(MyColor.bluecolor)
}.foregroundColor(MyColor.bluecolor)
```

[image]

Old DatePicker in iOS 13 without problem:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change DatePicker's texts color in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60560184/how-to-change-datepickers-texts-color-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have your colors but the following should work.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0)
{
    DatePicker(selection: self.$enddate, in: self.endMinDate()...self.endMaxDate()) {
        Text("Start")
    }.labelsHidden()
}
.accentColor(MyColor.bluecolor)  // << this one !!
//.accentColor(.red)             // << used for demo
```

Comment: Using system colors makes it easy to account for dark/light mode .accentColor(Color(uiColor: .label))