# Changing font color of Date Picker with inline style

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uidatepicker, ios14

I need to change the text color of my `.inline` style Date Picker.
A Google search led me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29220535/14016301) post.

This works perfectly on `.wheels` style, but doesn't work on `.inline`:
[image: ‏]

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
    
        self.datePicker.backgroundColor = .blue
    
        datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
        datePicker.tintColor = .systemTeal
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I assume no (at least not now). Apple uses collection view inside and set labelColor for each UILabel day explicitly in cell, so it does not react on any external appearance changes.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711760 - Nov 2023, still no textColor property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change `inline` styled Date Picker text color in `UIKit` 14, but here is a workaround you can try:

#### Override style

I noticed that if you change the theme of the device (between light and dark), the text color of the `.inline` date picker is changing.
So for example if you want a dark-text date picker in dark theme, you can override it:

```
myDatePicker.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

Heres a image of the result

[image]

I will keep this post updated if there is any new way to change to any color.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to change the font color to white, simply override the date picker's user interface style:

```
datePicker.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

Comment: Thanks, this works even though you can't change it to any color. I'll mark it as accepted for now