# Can you change the font size of a UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

In my application, I have several UIDatePickers that I need to take up about 2/3 of the screen. However, doing so currently, the month and year columns are getting truncated when in portrait. For example, instead of "2015" you'll see "..." or "Sept..." instead of "September." I've found how to scale and shrink the picker, but that doesn't seem to be fixing the problem at all.

So I was wondering if you could change the font size of the columns. That's the only way I can think of to allow all of the columns to fit short of making my own control. Which would seem incredibly unnecessary and prone to more errors when Apple already provides something with the same functionality. But if that's the only way..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55075201/2057955

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. ([Reference here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker))

An alternative would be to make your own version using [UIPickerView](http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/)

**As per the Documentation:**

- Appearance: The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.
- You should integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout. Although date pickers can be resized, they should be used at their intrinsic content size.*

Comment: Darn... Really hoped there would be. Any advice on how to maintain localization with a custom UIPickerView? That's the biggest reason I didn't want to go down that route.

Comment: If you're using NSDate you should be able to display localized or at least preference-based date formatting: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

For formatting the order of items in the picker... you could use currentLocale: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/currentLocale

This isn't by any means a full explanation, haven't thought it through fully - but hopefully it gets you on the right track!