# Change font type and size in uidatepicker in objective c

Tags: objective-c, categories, uidatepicker, uifont

I am able to change the font type and size by creating the categories and using below line :

```
  [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIDatePicker class]]] setAppearanceFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:14.0]];
```

It work fine.but problem is when i try to scroll the date font size and type get change to system(default) font type and size.
Please help me.
I want to make same font type through out my application.
and change the size of the font as per control.
Is there any way to handle this.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417217/set-text-color-and-font-for-uidatepicker-in-ios8-swift/33459744

Comment: @kb920 Thank you for the reply.But it only say textcolor I want to sent font style and size

Comment: I think you can't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789463/can-you-change-the-font-size-of-a-uidatepicker you need to design custom date picker in this case

Comment: @kb920 okay. Thank you