# Is it possible to change the IOS native date control's font size in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a date picker control in my Xamarin Ios App and upon analysis we found that there are a lot of date entry related issues customers are facing. We want to see if we can change this date control's font size which could help resolve this issue.

[image]

Any date picket style changes (using the xaml or writing custom renderers) are applicable to the text box which shows the selected date but I want to be able to alter the size of the native date control as depicted in the picture.

Is there a way to do so? I am also fine exploring other free date controls if any. Any suggestion in this regard will really help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789463/can-you-change-the-font-size-of-a-uidatepicker

Comment: What is the issue you are facing that you need to be able to change font size? That way I can recommend an alternative

Comment: We have a search feature which is based on the date selection. Basically we see the customers are selecting wrong date and trying to search. We are trying to increase the font so that it can help in selecting right date.

Comment: Did you try to use UIPickerView?